# Composition in OOP

Tags: c++, oop

I have a simple question regarding composition in the context of object oriented design.
In C++, if I were to implement some class to be composed of some other class, I would do the following:

```
class foo {

private : bar b; // composition (foo is composed of bar)
};
```

But if I do  the following :

```
class foo {
public:
      virtual ~foo()  {
          delete b;
          b = NULL;
   }
private : 
     bar *b = new bar();
}
```

Does this mean foo is composed of bar? I want to think it to be a long term association instead of composition (because size of foo does not increase due to bar;only the size of the pointer gets added extra) but can this also be thought of as composition?

Comment: Having asked 45 questions I find it surprising you do not know how to format code on SO....

Comment: It's still composition: "A foo *has a* bar". How the memory is arranged is an implementation detail, not part of the design.

Comment: unrelated, please use smart pointer

Comment: But what if bar could exist independently of foo also OR foo delegates the job of destroying bar to someone else in its destructor. Will this still be composition ?

Comment: @BryanChen - A smart pointer does not add any functionality or safety (in this specific case) over simply deleting the object in the destructor.  Smart pointers are very useful in some cases, but not so much in this case.

Comment: @MichaelJ it does add functionality. you get correct assign operator / copy constructor etc.

Comment: @BryanChen - I think we'll have to agree to disagree.  If the `bar` object was to be shared between multiple objects, then a shared_ptr would be appropriate.  However in this case, where `b` is allocated on construction, I would expect the copy constructor to duplicate the `b` object rather than share it or transfer ownership.  Doing this explicitly in the `foo` copy constructor makes it somewhat clearer.

Comment: @MichaelJ still. use `unique_ptr` makes it clearer

Comment: @BryanChen - I don't want to engage in "tis too / tis not".  I outlined my reasons above and you haven't convinced me they're wrong.  Lets agree to disagree.  unique_ptr is very useful in places, but not (in my opinion) here.